# Creating a boost::python::object from a std::function

Tags: c++, python, boost, c++11, boost-python

How can I construct a boost::python::object from a std::function ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Use `boost::python::make_function`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/python/doc/v2/make_function.html#make_function-spec), and provide a signature because the default one doesn't handle `std::function`.

For example, we want to wrap the return type of:

```
std::function<std::string(int, int)> get_string_function(const std::string& name)
{
    return [=](int x, int y)
    {
        return name + "(x=" + std::to_string(x) + ", y=" + std::to_string(y) + ")";
    };
}
```

We could define a wrapper and `def` using it:

```
boost::python::object get_string_function_pywrapper(const std::string& name)
{
    auto func = get_string_function(name);
    auto call_policies = boost::python::default_call_policies();
    typedef boost::mpl::vector<std::string, int, int> func_sig;
    return boost::python::make_function(func, call_policies, func_sig());
}

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(s)
{
    boost::python::def("get_string_function", get_string_function_pywrapper);
}
```

The Python side can now use the result as we want:

```python
>>> import s
>>> s.get_string_function("Coord")
<Boost.Python.function object at 0x1cca450>
>>> _(1, 4)
'Coord(x=1, y=4)'
```